# Is it valid to resolve promise in the promise constructor?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Is it valid to resolve the promise in the constructor like this

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('foo');
});
```

instead of the resolving after the construction creation like the following

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 300);
});
```

Comment: Sure, it works, it just seems silly to do so if `resolve` is called unconditionally in the constructor (why use a Promise at all if nothing is asynchronous?)

Comment: Your first example can be simplified to [`var promise1 = Promise.resolve('foo')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve). That function wouldn't exist if it wasn't a valid use-case

Comment: @CertainPerformance Promise return value type is expected by the framework's caller. But for my particular use case i do not have to wait to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly acceptable to resolve a new Promise synchronously in the constructor. IIRC, it is even a test case in the [A+ promise](https://promisesaplus.com/) validation suite.

However if the resolution is *not* conditional, it is more clearly achieved using the ES6 Promise static method `resolve':

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve( 'foo');
```

---

*Note* the two approaches differ if errors are thrown:

- If the executor throws an error, `new Promise( executor)` returns a rejected promise.

  If evaluation of the argument for `Promise.resolve` throws an error, the exception prevents a call to `Promise.resolve` taking place.